# Serializing List of POJOs using Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, orm

I have a Java class that is mapped to a database table using JPA.  Inside this class I have a `List<Code>` that I need to store in database.

So the `Code` class is not mapped into Hibernate.  Is there a way to Serialize the `List<Code>` without mapping the Code class into Hibernate?  Thanks in advance.

Error Message:

```
org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not insert collection [com.app.Account.codes#2]
```

Problem is that I'm getting error when Hibernate attempts to Serialize my List.

```
@Entity
@Table (name="account", catalog="database1")
public class Account{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column (name = "id")
    private String id

    @Column (name = "type")
    private String type;

    @CollectionOfElements
    @Column (name = "codes")
    List<Code> codes;
    ...
    ...
}


public class Code implements Serializable{
//This is a basic POJO that is not mapped into Hibernate. I just want this object
//to be stored in database.
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to annotate the codes field with `@Lob`, not with `@CollectionOfElements`.

See http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/reference/en-US/html_single/#d0e6099 and the following paragraph.

This is a very fragile way of persisting a list of objects, though, because it uses binary serialization, which might quickly become non-backward compatible if the list or the Code class changes. It's also impossible to query or inspect using database tools.

I would rather map the Code class as an entity or as an embeddable.