# Serialize a hibernate model and its lazy load objects

Tags: java, hibernate, serialization, deserialization

I have a hibernate model (say X) with lazy loading objects in it. When I serialize the model X, I want to serialize all its lazy load objects. How do I achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to be able to serialize your entities, make them implement Serializable.

Or You can use [SerializationHelper](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.0/javadocs/org/hibernate/internal/util/SerializationHelper.html) utility provided by hibernate. You can serialize or deserialize entities.

Or try putting `@Lob` annotation over the `Set` that you have. Look at here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8303017/4828463

Comment: But this is not serialising the objects in X, which are lazy load objects. I want to serialize all the lazy objects also

Comment: are those lazy load objects a collection of objects? If yes then goto then goto those object class and implement serializable? what happens then?

Comment: my class X has 2 collection entities say Set<A>, Set<B>.

class A has a object T where again class T structure is like this : 
It has few entity objects in it and also few set of entities.

Now when I serialize class X, it has to serialize Set<A>, Set<B> and all the nested objects in it. And all those are lazy load objects and yes all the objects are serializable.

Comment: try to put @Lob over those Sets variables? then tell me what happens. And also take a look here http://stackoverflow.com/a/8303017/4828463

Comment: From the reference you provided, I understand that @Lob helps to persist collection of nonhibernate models
My use case is like this 
I want to serialise a hibernate model and deserialise that model somewhere else. For this I used SerializanHelper to serialize object X (as I explained X has collection of hibernate models which are lazy load objects). When I deserialize the object X, I am getting null pointer exception. When I serialize X, the nested objects are not serialized because those are lazy load objects and they will have some value when getter is called. This is the issue I am facing

Answer (score 0):

My solution is to set the mapper prior to do the actual serialization:

```
ObjectMapper objMapper = new ObjectMapper();
objMapper.configure(SerializationFeature.FAIL_ON_EMPTY_BEANS, false);
```

This way, there was no attempt to populate relational objects, instead their ids were left intact, and so I could keep the fetch = FetchType.LAZY flag on my relational fields.

Comment: This skips the serialization, it doesn't solve the OP question.